# Close all tabs in Safari except for one

Tags: macos, safari, mojave, tabs

I spend an awful lot of time in Safari conducting research. As you can imagine this often results in me having lots of tabs open. So I find myself settling on one tab and wanting to close all the others except for the one I’m currently on.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes! You can do one of the following:

- right-click on the tab you want to keep and select the Close Other Tabs option, **or**
- make sure you’re on the tab you want and then use the <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> keyboard shortcut (or, if you prefer using the mouse, hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key and navigate to File > Close Other Tabs).

**NOTE:** - This closes all other tabs in the *same* window, not all tabs in all windows.

**BONUS:** You’ll find the above shortcuts are supported by most of the default macOS apps in macOS Mojave, including Finder, Terminal, etc. Some older macOS apps also support these, as do some 3rd party apps.

Comment: Just what the doctor ordered! :)

Comment: Xcode has option+click the X on the tab, too.